# Cherry-pick commits in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

New to VS 2019 and trying to split a larger change into several atomic commits. Say I have `file.cpp`:

#### Remote repo version

```
// Line 1
// Line 2
// Line 3
// Line 4
```

#### Local version

```
// Line 1a
// Line 2
// Line 3b
// Line 4
```

When I go to the `Team Explorer` tab, I can see that `file.cpp` has been changed. But I'd like to make two commits, one for `Line 1a` and a separate commit for `Line 3b`.

Is this possible in Visual Studio 2019? Or should I use an external tool such as `git-gui`?

Comment: It is not possible in VS 2019.The VS does not allow you to do partial commits. Meaning, selecting hunks or specific lines in a particular file to commit. Its either whole file or none.
As you've mentioned. Git-GUI can help you with this. Or, if you prefer, the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do via Visual Studio 2019.
Visual Studio, does not allow you selecting hunks or specific lines (of code), in a particular file to stage for commit.
It always stages the whole file.

Even the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commits?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) does not mention anything about it.

As you've mentioned.
You can use `Git-GUI`. Which does exactly what you desire or any other tool.
It can also be done via CLI, if you are in to it.